# Determining local IP address in P2P application

Tags: winapi, sockets, udp, winsock

I am developing an P2P application where a peers talk to the server to inform its Private and Public IP. The application uses UDP for communication.

To get the private IP the client uses `gethostbyname` and bind it to that IP. The problem is when the system has more than one NIC. The problem is when one of the NIC is not connected to internet. So to avoid it i am using `INADDR_ANY` and bind it.

Now i need to get my local IP address to inform to the server. Is there any API which will tell me which IP address of the NIC is active?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to an explicit IP address rather than `INADDR_ANY` as binding to `INADDR_ANY` will mean that calling `getsockname()` on the socket to get the local address will simply return `INADDR_ANY`.

So, what you need to do is iterate the available endpoints (using `getaddrinfo()`) and create a socket on each. These will then give you the correct address if you call `getsockname()` on them later.

Comment: We cannot use a particular IP to bind it because we never know which IP is active. Thats why i am  using INADDR_ANY to bind so that any packet arrived is delivered appropriately.

Comment: That's why I suggest that you iterate through ALL interfaces and bind to each. If you also want to handle new interfaces being added, etc, then you need to also listen for interface changes. Binding to `INADDR_ANY` will always cause `getsockname()` to return `INADDR_ANY` as that's what the socket is bound to.

Comment: if i bind to all the address how will i determine which IP i am using to send the data? is there any way in the server to determine the clients private IP

Comment: You bind one socket to each available IP. If the client connects to you then you will know the IP, by querying the socket that the recvFrom completed on using `getsockname()`. You then respond on the same socket. You can find out the client's public IP by calling `getpeername()` on the socket. You may need to consider NAT issues.

Comment: Use `connect()`, which works for UDP as well as TCP (for UDP, since it is connectionless, `connect()` will simply lock down which interface is used for all UDP packets on that socket).  After `connect()` returns success, `getsockname()` will not return `INADDR_ANY` anymore (according to WinSock documentation, you may have to perform I/O on the UDP socket first before `getsockname()` can then know the local interface).